# How to convert list to stream with JMESPath?

Tags: jmespath

Consider this Json:

```
[
    {
        "Path": "/abc"
    },
    {
        "Path": "/"
    }
]
```

Using jq the list can be converted to a stream of json documents using `.[]`

```
{
"Path": "/abc"
}
{
"Path": "/"
}
```

What's the way to do this with JMESPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMESPath has no concept of streams as they exist in jq. The output of a JMESPath search is always a single JSON entity. That entity can be an array, of course, but since you already have an array I assume that's not what you want.

Some – but not all – of the things that you can do with jq streams can be done with the flatten operator `[]`, the multi-select operator `[*]` and the `map(&expr, arr)` function, but each problem will need to be tackled differently.